# Google Maps API v3 geocoding web service with key to monitor usage

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am trying to implement a server side call to geocoding with a given address in C#. I understand that the geocoding web service does not require an API key to work. I also understand that sensor param is required. I have all of these checked out fine. I went to Google Console to request a server-side key hoping that I can track the usage for all the web service geocoding calls in my application, which is based on the ip address.

So, here is the request, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=21274+WOODMERE+DRIVE+LEONARDTOWN+MD&sensor=false&key=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

where aaaaaaaaaaaaa is the actual key. I initialized this call from the correct server. But yet I am still getting a REQUEST_DENIED status every time.

So my question is, how I do achieve the goal of being able to check the usage from the Google Console with the Google Maps API geocoding web service? Or geocoding web service cannot be tracked because it's not a client side API?

Thank you and hope you can shed some light for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, there's no support for api key in geocoding request and it seems intentional per api documentation. The current parameter is a legacy from V2, and in the api console there isn't an available service for geocoding api.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en#Limits

So, stick to keyless requests, and if you want to monitor your usage, you should log yourself and watch for OVER_QUERY_LIMIT responses.

Comment: Like you said, that's what our app exactly does now: to not using any key for the web service and log the usage ourselves via log4net. Thanks for your time answering this.